# Getting an error when trying to use 'xstring' commands in my macro

Tags: macros, errors, xstring

When I try to compile the minimal example below, I get an error:

```
! Argument of \@xs@StrLeft has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.33 \setInSCCF{abcdef}
```

If I switch the usage of `\setInSC` to `\textbf` in the `\setInSCCF` command, then it works. So there must be something related to the `\setInSC` command. However, `\setInSC` works fine when used on its own. I tried expanding the argument first but to no avail (don't know if I did it correctly, though).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\setInSC}[1]{%
  \ifx\f@shape\code@Roman
    \expandafter\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}%
  \else
    \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
      \begingroup
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
      \let\MakeTextLowercase\@firstofone
      \expandafter\MakeUppercase{#1}%
      \endgroup
    \else
      \expandafter\MakeTextUppercase{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\code@Roman}{n}
\newcommand*{\code@Italics}{it}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\setInSCCF}[1]{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}\setInSC{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}{}}%
}


\begin{document}
\setInSCCF{abcdef}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you tell us what the macros are supposed to do?

Comment: @egreg: The macro is suppose to always capitalize the first letter, and set the remainder in small caps using `\setInSC`. Just realized now that the first letter is just left untouched, but that's another problem. =)

Comment: None of the `\expandafter` do anything here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use `StrGobbleLeft` as an argument of a command. You need a temp-command to save the result.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\setInSCCF}[1]{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\tempa]%
  \setInSC{\tempa}%
}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\setInSC}[1]{%
  \ifx\f@shape\code@Roman
    \textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}%
  \else
    \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
      \begingroup
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
      \let\MakeTextLowercase\@firstofone
      \MakeUppercase{#1}%
      \endgroup
    \else
      \MakeTextUppercase{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\code@Roman}{n}
\newcommand*{\code@Italics}{it}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\setInSCCF}[1]{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\tempa]%
  \setInSC{\tempa}%
}


\begin{document}
\setInSCCF{abcdef}
\end{document}
```

To split the string you can avoid `xstring` with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\setIn#1{\@setIn#1\@nil}
\def\@setIn#1#2\@nil{%
Input One: #1\par
Input two: #2%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setIn{abcdef}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, because you've removed the macro `\setInSCCF`, which was the one I had problems with. `\setInSCCF` invokes `\setInSC`, which works fine.

Comment: I want to capitalize the first letter, and set the remainder in small caps. For this, I need to split the string, for which I use `xstring`.

Comment: @gablin: Now I understand your question. Please see my edits

Comment: I read up on how `xstring` works and realized the same thing (that the xstring commands cannot be expanded), but I'll accept your answer since you probably beat me to it. =)